# About RewriteRule and .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url

I have a problem:

I want to rewrite this:

```
example.com/pages/?page=start
```

or

```
example.com/pages/?page=news
```

to:

```
example.com/start
```

or

```
example.com/news
```

So I want the GET from the subpage to be displayed as a main page, does anyone know how?

Comment: Do you want a rewrite or a redirect or both? What should the user see and what is the URL that the server understand?

Answer (score 1):

If you want that the user enter something like `example.com/start` or `example.com/news` but the server should process it like `example.com/pages/?page=start` or `example.com/pages/?page=news` this is done as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+) /pages/?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Be careful here because `example.com/news/first-news` will also be rewritten to `example.com/pages/?page=news` and `/first-news` will be lost!

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but how would you handle to not lose "/first-news" in this example?

Comment: Do you want to have soma extra query parameter (e.g. /pages/?page=news&subpage=first-news) or is it only one parameter (e.g. /pages/?page=news/first-news)? If you want to have extra query parameter how many because what about example.com/news/first-news/sub-page/sub-sub-page/?

Comment: Extra parameter please, so I can work with it in seperated _GET variables